# Memory Leak in using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode5

In my project I manually create views without using storyboard. I have tried to play a Video when I tap an image. It works fine. But everytime when I check it shows memory leak when I tap the image, I have searched about this a lot and applied but no use.
 In my Appdelegate.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *theMoviePlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *image1;
```

In .m file:

```
-(void) startPage{
.....
_image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.window.frame.size.width/2)-25, 40, 50, 50)];
[_image1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
_image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_2.jpg"];
_tapImage1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(image1Tapped:)];
[_image1 addGestureRecognizer:_tapImage1];
.....}
```

In imageTapped(),

```
-(void) image1Tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  .....

 [_image1 removeFromSuperview];

 _theMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];


    [_theMoviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];

    [_theMoviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-55, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];



    [_theMoviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];

    UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    [backgroundWindow addSubview:_theMoviePlayer.view];

    [_theMoviePlayer.view bringSubviewToFront:backgroundWindow];
[_theMoviePlayer play];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinished:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_theMoviePlayer];
...}
```

I get a memory leak everytime it enters imageTapped: method. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remove observer after notification done it's job?

Comment: Ya I did. But there's not the leak happening, it starts when it enters in to imageTapped: method as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, its with the device iPad(iOS version 5). It shows no leaks when I checked with iPad4 (iOS version 7).

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *theMoviePlayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *image1;
```

another think is that your `theMoviePlayer` is not remove, try to make its view transparency for see if is already working behind the new one

Comment: Ya did that too, I cant see my images when app loaded, it get released before display.

Comment: if you remove the image is not the same that you release is have you checked that in instrument ?

Comment: Then how it could be released. I checked for leaks in Instrument tool, it shows leak starting form '[MPMoviePlayerController setControlStyle:]' line.

Comment: what do you do in the movieFinished: method?

Comment: This is what I did                             'MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [anotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];[_theMoviePlayer stop];
    _theMoviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
[_theMoviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];'

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to help you.

In -(void) startPage you  allocate _image1 object

And you are removing object in  method **-(void) image1Tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender**
using **[_image1 removeFromSuperview];** method

means now _image1 is nil and when  **-(void) image1Tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender** method called at that time when u fetch _image1 object at that time _image1 is already nil 
**so its give Memory Leak warning.**

**And solution for this one is:**

1.****Show/Hide _image1 object**** or 
every time you  need to do proper  allocation  and remove image1 object in this method  **-(void) image1Tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender**, based your requirement.

First try this solution and there will be Memory Leak Warning removed.

The Compiler check all over steps in advance so it recognize  as Warning.

In Some cases if your logic is wrong then compiler inform us Wrong logic.

if u want to check that click on blue arrow of memory warning button it will give exaplanation of your logic or warning with assumption.

Comment: Ya Thank you, but here I am reusing views to prevent memory leak, so I have allocated my view, imageView in startPage() method and then removed both my view and imageView in image1Tapped() method and allocated a new view for my video play. I didn't mentioned that in my question as I have checked that without playing my video, it shows no leaks there.

Comment: Tried that too.. No use.